# Python .index & .map( ) gives 'Series' object is not callable error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have two excels I coverted into dataframes.

DF1: contains columns 'JobKeys' and 'Aircraft Numbers' (Amongst other data)

DF2: contains columns 'JobKeys' and 'Shortage' (Amongst other data)

I want to create a column 'Short' in DF1 mapping for the jobkeys present in DF2 (effectively a VLOOKUP)

For both I set JobKey as the index:

```
#Import relevant libraries:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DF1 = pd.read_excel('...')
DF2 = pd.read.excel('...')

DF1['Short'] = " "

DF1.set_index('JobKey', inplace = True)
DF2.set_index('JobKey', inplace = True)
```

Both OK. I print a sample of both using DF.head() and it looks OK. I want to use .index.map() what was done here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/vlookup-implementation-in-python-in-three-simple-steps-93b5a290fd72

```
DF1["Short"]=DF1.index.map(DF2["Shortage"])
```

However I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in map(self, mapper)
   2439         applied : array
   2440         """
-> 2441         return self._arrmap(self.values, mapper)
   2442 
   2443     def isin(self, values, level=None):

pandas\src\algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas.algos.arrmap_object (pandas\algos.c:46681)()

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable


-------
```

Any ideas as to why? it seems pretty straight forward yet I can't find the cause of my problem.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Doesn't look like you need to do any map here... just allow the indices to naturally align... try: `DF1['Short'] = DF2['Shortage']`...?